# Not Redirecting Ok Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am sorry to bother you again so quickly with another problem yet i can't see the cause ... and i am looking at my code for quite some time(i am noob...). The documents that i think need a look at are displayrecord.jsp, DisplayData servlet, editdata.jsp and EditRecord servlet. If anyone has the time please do help me , it just shows me a blank page when i hit that Edit button....

Index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>:::::Employees::::</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="insertrecord.jsp">Create New Employee</a></li>
        <li><a href="DisplayData">Display Employees</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Database Connection Clase:

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class DatabaseConnection {

Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet res;

public DatabaseConnection(){

}
public Connection setConnection(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/emp";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
    }catch(Exception e){ }
    return conn;
}
public ResultSet getResult(String sql,Connection conn){
    this.conn = conn;
    try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    }catch(Exception e){ }

    return res;
}
```

}

displayrecord.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function editRecord(id){
                url = "EditRecord";
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:8084/ZaSkillz/"+url+"?id="+id;

            }
        </script>
        <table align = "center" border="2px" width="80%">
            <%Iterator itr;%>
            <%List data = (List) request.getAttribute("EmpData");
            for(itr = data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
                %>
                <tr>
                    <% String s = (String) itr.next();%>
                    <td><%= s %></td>
                    <td><%= itr.next() %></td>
                    <td><%= itr.next() %></td>
                    <td><%= itr.next() %></td>
                    <td><input type= "submit" value = "Edit" name="edit" onclick="editRecord(<%=s%>);"></td>
                    <td><input type= "submit" value = "Delete" name="delete" onclick="deleteRecord(<%=s%>);"></td>
                    <%}%>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

DisplayData Servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class DisplayData extends HttpServlet {

    String query;
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet res;

    DatabaseConnection dbconn;
    List lst = new ArrayList();

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            dbconn = new DatabaseConnection();
            conn = dbconn.setConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            query = "SELECT * from emp";
            res = dbconn.getResult(query, conn);
            while(res.next()){
                lst.add(res.getString("id"));
                lst.add(res.getString("ename"));
                lst.add(res.getString("desg"));
                lst.add(res.getString("sal"));
            }
            res.close();


        }catch(Exception e){
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } 
        finally {
            request.setAttribute("EmpData", lst);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayrecord.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            lst.clear();
            out.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

EditRecord Servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class EditRecord extends HttpServlet {

    Connection conn;
    ResultSet res;
    Statement stmt;
    String id,query;
    DatabaseConnection dbconn;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
             id= request.getParameter("id");
             dbconn = new DatabaseConnection();
             conn = dbconn.setConnection();
             stmt = conn.createStatement();
             query = "SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE id= "+ id ;
             res = dbconn.getResult(query, conn);


        }
        catch(Exception e){ out.println(e);}
        finally {
            request.setAttribute("EditData",res);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/editdata.jsp");
            out.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

editdata.jsp :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> WTF</h1>
        <form action="EditRecord" method="post">
        <table border ="1px" width ="80%">


                <%ResultSet res = (ResultSet) request.getAttribute("EditData");%>
                <%if(res.next()){
                    %>

                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="id" value=<%=res.getString("id")%> /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Ename</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="ename" value=<%=res.getString("ename")%> /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Designation</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="desg" value=<%=res.getString("desg")%> /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Salary</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sal" value=<%=res.getString("sal")%> /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Update" name="update"></td>
                    </tr>



            <%}%>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InsertData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>InsertData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DisplayData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>DisplayData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EditRecord</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>EditRecord</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InsertData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/InsertData</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DisplayData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DisplayData</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EditRecord</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/EditRecord</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: did you put a break point at EditRecord processRequest methdod. Did the code hit there? Did you get any exceptions? Can you share your web.xml where you do the url mappings?

Comment: break point where ? the code is written as up there did i miss something?. Yes code hits http://localhost:8084/ZaSkillz/EditRecord?id=122 . I do not get any exceptions that would be a good thing , i just get a blank page :D

Comment: i guess u forgot doing rd.forward(request, response) on your edit servlet..

Comment: my god... yes you are right . Now i get java.lang.NullPointerException we are getting somewhere!

Comment: Exception report

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /editdata.jsp at line 17

14:             
15:             
16:                 <%ResultSet res = (ResultSet) request.getAttribute("EditData");%>
17:                 <%if(res.next()){
18:                     %>
19:                     
20:                     <tr>

Comment: try fetching data in servlet, do not pass resultset to the jsp, like you did in your DisplayData servlet.

Comment: AND DONE ! :)))) mr acemrek i love you very very much not in a million years would i have thought i forgot something like that rd...... !

Comment: ah i did that at another project since i am studying Java Script and Java Query at another subject at my university i wanted to try it this way also :D How do i give you much reputation? :))